# Using if/else to define const in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constants

I'm using **const** in a function to define a few variables as follows

```
const printBlock.format({
  name : this.matchedData.clientName,
  date : this.matchedData.jobDate,
  destination : this.matchedData.address,
  apartment : this.matchedData.address2,
  stateZip : this.matchedData.zipcode
})
```

From then, I'm printing out all of these things in order that they're declared. However, some of the data doesn't have an apartment number so it'll show up as:

John Doe

6/6/2018

135 Testdemo Avenue

null

NY 11111

Is it possible to use an if function within declaring the consts in order to make it so that:

```
if (this.matchedData.address2 == null){
//Do nothing
} else {
apartment : this.matchedData.address2,
}
```

Comment: `const printBlock({…})` is a syntax error. What are you actually doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var object = {
  address: '1111',
  apartment : this.matchedData.address2 ? "" : this.matchedData.address2
}
```

Comment: This approach will also create a property even if it's null

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me! I ended up formatting as follows:

`apartment : ((this.matchedData.address2 !== null) ? this.matchedData.address2 : ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and check with property and if not `null`, take an object for assignment.

```
printBlock(Object.assign(
    {
        name: this.matchedData.clientName,
        date: this.matchedData.jobDate,
        destination: this.matchedData.address,
        apartment: this.matchedData.address2,
        stateZip: this.matchedData.zipcode
    }, 
    this.matchedData.address2 === null || { apartment: this.matchedData.address2 }    
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your object first without the apartment entry and then add the apartment entry if it is not null...

```
const a = {
  name : this.matchedData.clientName,
  date : this.matchedData.jobDate,
  destination : this.matchedData.address,
  stateZip : this.matchedData.zipcode
};

if (this.matchedData.address2 !== null){
  a.apartment : this.matchedData.address2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const printBlock({...})` will throw an error because it isn't a valid way to initialize a constant. If `printBlock` is a function, why not handle null values in the body of `printBlock`?

```
function printBlock(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop]) {
            console.log(obj[prop]); // or do whatever you mean by 'print'
        }
    }
}
```